# Posicionar option según escriba en Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Amigos buen día, tengo un `selector` con sus `option`, mediante un `css` he logrado insertar una bandera en un `input`, y al seleccionar un `option` se posiciona su bandera mediante un `javascript` que actualiza un `span` con `position` de la bandera y ademas pone el anexo según el país seleccionado, hasta ahí bien.

Ahora si el usuario no busca en el `option` para escoger su anexo de su pais, sino decide escribirlo manualmente, como podría posicionar la bandera en el `input` mediante un `javascript`.

mi código

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function() {
    $("#phone").focus();
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#phone').val(value);
    var position = $(this).find(':selected').data('position');
    $('.c-input-phone-country__flag__img').css({
      'background-position': `0px ${position}`
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.bp_form__field {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.bp_form__field__label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

label {
  cursor: default;
}

.bp_form__field--phone .c-input-phone-country {
  display: inline-block;
}

.c-input-phone-country {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.c-input-phone-country__country {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 32px;
  bottom: 1px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

select:not(:-internal-list-box) {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

select {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: pre;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: default;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

select {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}

.bp_form__field--phone .c-input-phone-country .c-input-phone-country__flag {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}

.c-input-phone-country__flag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 32px;
  bottom: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.c-input-phone-country__flag:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\25BC';
  top: 50%;
  left: 23px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  font-size: 6px;
}

element.style {
  background-position: 0px -300px;
}

.c-input-phone-country__flag__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  background: url(http://subirimagen.me/uploads/20190112010658.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 25px;
  display: block;
}

.bp_form__field--phone .c-input-phone-country #phone {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.bp_input_text {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 25px 6px 2px;
  zoom: 1;
  height: 19px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

input {
  padding-left: .3em;
}

input {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  cursor: text;
  padding: 1px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}

.c-input-phone-country__input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div data-component="" class="bp_form__field bp_form__field--phone ">
  <label for="phone" class="bp_form__field__label">
    Teléfono / movil
    </label>
  <div data-component="input-phone-country" class="c-input-phone-country" data-phone-country-default="pe">
    <select id="mySelect" class="c-input-phone-country__country" tabindex="-1" data-phone-country="">
      <option value="+ 376" data-position="-1px">Andorra</option>
      <option value="+ 971" data-position="-25px">Emiratos Árabes Unidos</option>
      <option value="+ 93" data-position="-50px">Afganistán</option>
      <option value="+ 1268" data-position="-75px">Antigua y Barbuda</option>
      <option value="+ 1264" data-position="-100px">Anguila</option>
      <option value="+ 355" data-position="-125px">Albania</option>
      <option value="+ 374" data-position="-150px">Armenia</option>
      <option value="+ 244" data-position="-200px">Angola</option>
      <option value="+ 672" data-position="-225px">Antártida</option>
      <option value="+ 54" data-position="-250px">Argentina</option>
      <option value="+ 1684" data-position="-275px">Samoa Americana</option>
      <option value="+ 43" data-position="-300px">Austria</option>
      <option value="+ 61" data-position="-325px">Australia</option>
      <option value="+ 297" data-position="-350px">Aruba</option>
      <option value="+ 994" data-position="-400px">Azerbaiyán</option>
      <option value="+ 387" data-position="-425px">Bosnia y Herzegovina</option>
      <option value="+ 1246" data-position="-450px">Barbados</option>
      <option value="+ 880" data-position="-475px">Bangladesh</option>
      <option value="+ 32" data-position="-500px">Bélgica</option>
      <option value="+ 226" data-position="-525px">Burkina Faso</option>
      <option value="+ 359" data-position="-550px">Bulgaria</option>
      <option value="+ 973" data-position="-575px">Bahréin</option>
      <option value="+ 257" data-position="-600px">Burundi</option>
      <option value="+ 229" data-position="-625px">Benín</option>
    </select>
    <span class="c-input-phone-country__flag"><span class="c-input-phone-country__flag__img" data-phone-flag="" style="background-position: 0px -250px;"></span></span>
    <input id="phone" class="bp_form__field__input bp_input_text bp_phone_input_with_help_message
    c-input-phone-country__input
    " type="text" name="phone" required="" value="+25" size="20" data-phone-input="" aria-describedby="bp_form_phone_msg" placeholder="+54976258412">
  </div>
</div>

<span> al escribir un codigo del pais se coloque su bandera <span/>
```

la bandera se actualiza en el `span`: `background-position`

```
<span class="c-input-phone-country__flag__img" data-phone-flag="" style="background-position: 0px -250px;"></span>
```

Answer (score -1):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
$(function() {
 $(document).on('keyup', '#phone', function(e) {
    let code = $(this).val().replace("+","").trim();
    if(code.length >= 2){
     $("option").each(function(){
       if($(this).val().replace("+","").trim() == code){
        var position = $(this).attr('data-position');
        $('.c-input-phone-country__flag__img').css({
          'background-position': `0px ${position}`
        });
       }
     });
    }
 })

  $(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function() {
$("#phone").focus();
var value = $(this).val();
$('#phone').val(value);
var position = $(this).find(':selected').data('position');
$('.c-input-phone-country__flag__img').css({
  'background-position': `0px ${position}`
});
  });
});
```

```css
.bp_form__field {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.bp_form__field__label {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

label {
  cursor: default;
}

.bp_form__field--phone .c-input-phone-country {
  display: inline-block;
}

.c-input-phone-country {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.c-input-phone-country__country {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 32px;
  bottom: 1px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

select:not(:-internal-list-box) {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

select {
  border-radius: 0px;
  border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: pre;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: default;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

select {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}

.bp_form__field--phone .c-input-phone-country .c-input-phone-country__flag {
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  top: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  right: 2px;
}

.c-input-phone-country__flag {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
  width: 32px;
  bottom: 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
}

.c-input-phone-country__flag:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '\25BC';
  top: 50%;
  left: 23px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  font-size: 6px;
}

element.style {
  background-position: 0px -300px;
}

.c-input-phone-country__flag__img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 2px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: -9px;
  background: url(http://subirimagen.me/uploads/20190112010658.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 25px;
  display: block;
}

.bp_form__field--phone .c-input-phone-country #phone {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.bp_input_text {
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px 25px 6px 2px;
  zoom: 1;
  height: 19px;
  line-height: 23px;
}

input {
  padding-left: .3em;
}

input {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
  cursor: text;
  padding: 1px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: initial;
  border-image: initial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button {
  text-rendering: auto;
  color: initial;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  text-indent: 0px;
  text-shadow: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0em;
  font: 400 13.3333px Arial;
}

input,
textarea,
select,
button,
meter,
progress {
  -webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
}

.c-input-phone-country__input {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div data-component="" class="bp_form__field bp_form__field--phone ">
  <label for="phone" class="bp_form__field__label">
    Teléfono / movil
    </label>
  <div data-component="input-phone-country" class="c-input-phone-country" data-phone-country-default="pe">
    <select id="mySelect" class="c-input-phone-country__country" tabindex="-1" data-phone-country="">
      <option value="+ 376" data-position="-1px">Andorra</option>
      <option value="+ 971" data-position="-25px">Emiratos Árabes Unidos</option>
      <option value="+ 93" data-position="-50px">Afganistán</option>
      <option value="+ 1268" data-position="-75px">Antigua y Barbuda</option>
      <option value="+ 1264" data-position="-100px">Anguila</option>
      <option value="+ 355" data-position="-125px">Albania</option>
      <option value="+ 374" data-position="-150px">Armenia</option>
      <option value="+ 244" data-position="-200px">Angola</option>
      <option value="+ 672" data-position="-225px">Antártida</option>
      <option value="+ 54" data-position="-250px">Argentina</option>
      <option value="+ 1684" data-position="-275px">Samoa Americana</option>
      <option value="+ 43" data-position="-300px">Austria</option>
      <option value="+ 61" data-position="-325px">Australia</option>
      <option value="+ 297" data-position="-350px">Aruba</option>
      <option value="+ 994" data-position="-400px">Azerbaiyán</option>
      <option value="+ 387" data-position="-425px">Bosnia y Herzegovina</option>
      <option value="+ 1246" data-position="-450px">Barbados</option>
      <option value="+ 880" data-position="-475px">Bangladesh</option>
      <option value="+ 32" data-position="-500px">Bélgica</option>
      <option value="+ 226" data-position="-525px">Burkina Faso</option>
      <option value="+ 359" data-position="-550px">Bulgaria</option>
      <option value="+ 973" data-position="-575px">Bahréin</option>
      <option value="+ 257" data-position="-600px">Burundi</option>
      <option value="+ 229" data-position="-625px">Benín</option>
    </select>
    <span class="c-input-phone-country__flag"><span class="c-input-phone-country__flag__img" data-phone-flag="" style="background-position: 0px -250px;"></span></span>
    <input id="phone" class="bp_form__field__input bp_input_text bp_phone_input_with_help_message
    c-input-phone-country__input
    " type="text" name="phone" required="" value="+25" size="20" data-phone-input="" aria-describedby="bp_form_phone_msg" placeholder="+54976258412">
  </div>
</div>

<span> al escribir un codigo del pais se coloque su bandera <span/>
```

Comment: Hola Bryro, las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad. Deberías editar tu respuesta para añadir algo más de detalle: ¿qué es lo que has cambiado? ¿por qué esos cambios solucionan el problema? Lee [answer] para más información.